# jQuery RegEx test returning undefined

Tags: jquery, regex

I've toyed with this for the last hour and am finally asking for some advice/help on what's causing this issue. I'm creating a small fallback using RegEx, the first input works fine, but the second returns undefined. Here's the HTML:

```
<input type="email" value="this@matches.com" />
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" value="ABC" />
```

You'll see from the jsFiddle and Console that it prints 'Success' for the type="email" input, but returns undefined for the pattern fallback. I basically want to reuse the same function and pass the parameters into it and get the value returned dynamically.

I have a feeling this might be the issue line:

```
var patternFallback = $(this).attr('pattern')
```

... Perhaps it somehow needs 'converting' for the JS to read it as RegEx?

Here's my jsFiddle if you can help, and thank you! The script is a section of the full code, which includes the problem area, the loop through elements and the variables I'm passing through the function: http://jsfiddle.net/fTk7e/

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `$(this).attr('pattern')` outside of any sort of event handler.  Therefore `this` is not your element.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, that's meant to be inside the loop. However, the answer below is what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var patternFallback = $(this).attr('pattern')
```

The value of 'this' where you are calling the function is a reference to the document object. You need to move this variable definition inside your each() call. This is why you're getting undefined.

And you should be creating a regular expression out of the string. You can't call .test() on a string.

```
var patternFallback = RegExp($(this).attr('pattern'));
```

Comment: Thanks nderscore, slight type 'RexExp' though! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
new RegExp($(this).attr('pattern'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rocket Hazman. Give the inputs an ID and test it that way.

```
<input id="myEmailId" type="email" value="this@matches.com" />
<input id="myTextId" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" value="ABC" />
```

And in javascript:

```
var patternFallback = $("#myTextId").attr('pattern');
```

Comment: Thanks Erik. I had meant to include the $(this) within the $.each loop, and what I needed was the new RegExp($(this).attr('pattern'));